# Python Class to create dataframe from csv file, modify dataframe, and return dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

At the moment I have multiple functions setup whereby the first function creates a pandas dataframe from a csv file. The following several functions then modify the dataframe (adds columns, formats columns, deletes columns etc.).

I want to do these same steps for several different files. Is it possible to create a class to replicates these steps where my functions would then be methods? Essentially the class would just be a data cleaning/formatting class.

Some of the functions so far are:

```
def TrimExtraWhitespace(df, list_of_columns):
    """Takes a list of columns in a dataframe and removes any extra whitespaces in the text"""

def convertDateColumnsToStr(df, list_of_columns):
    """Takes a list of columns in a dataframe and converts them to a string datatype"""

def parseUsernameFromColumn(df):
    """Uses regex to parse the username from the TEXT column"""
```

So I think my class and use case should be something like:

```
class ModifyDataFrame(original_dataframe)

new_modified_dataframe = ModifyDataFrame(original_dataframe)
```

where the new dataframe has the original dataframe as an input and then the class has cleaned/formatted it.

Thanks

Comment: should be edit, hard to read

Comment: It would be entirely possible to create a class to do this, but a potentially easier first step might just to run everything through a for loop.